# ExecuteSqlScriptwithTransaction: failed with exception ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to run below query(Sql Server) I get exception saying

> ExecuteSqlScriptwithTransaction: failed with exception ALTER DATABASE
>   statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)

IF((SELECT (size * 8 /1024.0)*1000 FROM sys.database_files df WHERE df.name like 'Test') < 9000000)  
   BEGIN    
      SET @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N''Test'', SIZE = 10000000KB );'
      EXEC (@sql)          
  END 

GO
```

Tried like below but same error

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)

IF((SELECT (size * 8 /1024.0)*1000 FROM sys.database_files df WHERE df.name like 'Test') < 9000000)
BEGIN
ALTER DATABASE Test MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'Test', SIZE = 10000000KB )
END

GO
```

Comment: Is your script larger then this snippit?  maybe you have a transaction and this is inside it?

Comment: @Brad That is the complete script...I have not added any transaction...I am not good in Sql so I am not sure if I have to add transaction here...

Comment: No, it was a thought because it is not clear on the question that was just a thought based on your error.  I think the answer below may work for you/

Comment: [You've got an ambient transaction](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56547) open somewhere. 'rollback transaction' before you execute it or open a new Connection.

Answer (score 2):

The `ExecuteSqlScriptwithTransaction` method named in the title suggests the code executes the script in a transaction. The [ALTER DATABASE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql) specifically states:

> The ALTER DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default
>   transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or
>   implicit transaction.

So the solution is to execute the script using a different method, one without an explict transaction.